# How to mark html.textbox to be requiered on Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model where i want to be mark all my Textbox like there are requiered. How can i do that ?

Can you help me.

Sorry for my little baby english, but i am French.

```
<%= Html.TextBox("login_user")%>
<%= Html.ValidationMessage("login_user", "*")%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model for this view you need to put `[Required]` attribute on `login_user` property. (btw, `login_user` is not a good choice for a property name as it does not fit the widely accepted convention)

So, you'd have something like:

```
class LoginModel {
  [Required]
  string LoginUser {get; set;}

  // the rest of your properties
  ...

}
```

In the view use `Html.EditorFor`.